# Can I change the appearance of the search box in expression engine?

Tags: ee2, search, css

Perhaps this is a noobish questions but, I am learning EE so here goes.

This is the code I have for my search box on my website.

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="video_tutorials"}
        <p>
               <label for="keywords">Search:</label>
             <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
         </p>
    {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

I am wondering, is there a way I can change this appearance on my website. For instance I would like to display the word "search" inside of the input area where a user would enter their search text. I would also like to make the white box longer. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This is quite simple, and why I prefer EE over other systems. It easily allows you to customize your markup anyway you want to. The `{exp:search:simple_form}` tag has two parameters to let you target and style the form with CSS ([Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#parameters)). `form_id` & `form_css`.

Re: placeholder text for the input, you can add the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute to the form. If you want to support older browsers, you will need to do this with JS.

```
{exp:search:simple_form form_id="my_form" channel="video_tutorials"}
        <p>
               <label for="keywords">Search:</label>
             <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100" placeholder="Search...">
         </p>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Comment: Here is my code now: `{exp:search:simple_form form_class="searchbox" channel="video_tutorials"}
          <p>
                 <label for="keywords">Search:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
          </p>
  {/exp:search:simple_form}`. 
My CSS looks like 

`.searchbox {
height: 10px; 
width:  150px; 
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: blue;
text-align:left;
}`.  Am I wrong on creating "searchbox"?

Comment: Adding the `form_class` parameter adds a class to the form itself. Therefore in your css, `.searchbox` is targeting the `<form>`. To target the keywords input field itself you should add a class to the tag or use `.searchbox input[type=text]` or just `#keywords`.

Comment: if I use .searchbox, would I simply just replace form_class"searchbox" with it? or would I need to make a div within the simple form tags? My end goal is to make the text input area a larger box.

Comment: Leave the `form_class="searchbox"` as is, and like Jason said, target the input with `.searchbox input[type="text"]` or use the ID of the input `#keywords` in your stylesheet

Comment: I have the #keywords working, so I can go in a tweak it now to how I want it. Thank you both so much for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark.